# How to unappend text from a DynamicQueryBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a `DynamicQueryBuilder` and selecting the various columns through the database, this is done by appending text to the `DynamicQueryBuilder`. Is there a way to unappend the text based on a condition?

```
DynamicQueryBuilder sql = new DynamicQueryBuilder();
sql.Append(@"SELECT TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 FROM Table);
```

I want to unappend TextBox3 based on a condition e.g:

```
if (!list.Contains(2)) 
{
     //unappend TextBox2 from sql.Append 
}
```

Comment: If you're creating the DynamicQueryBuilder, how's about writing yourself an 'Unappend' method?  How is the appended value stored inside the DQB?  As a string?  If so, string has a [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) method so use that to replace whatever you want with string.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check at the time of appending?

```
DynamicQueryBuilder sql = new DynamicQueryBuilder();
if(!list.Contains(2)) 
{ 
    sql.Append(@"SELECT TextBox1, TextBox2 FROM Table");
} 
else
{
    sql.Append(@"SELECT TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 FROM Table");
}
```

Comment: im sure most programmers can have that logic sorted, therefore my question is a bit different and is related to a program that i'm writting

Comment: Then I strongly recommend you clarify your question and provide more details.